# Jupyter Kernel taking too long to start and sometimes gets stuck

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, miniconda, python-3.11

I run jupyter notebook(version: 6.5.4) in Chrome. Recently, chrome crashed due to computation intensive code I've been running in jupyter. From then, kernel is not starting immediately and sometimes, some cells aren't run. They get stuck. You can see that in below image.

**Here is the terminal output while starting the kernel:**

```
[I 10:59:28.722 NotebookApp] Kernel started: bfb0ee3c-d2e6-40ca-9960-ca438254d0e7, name: python3
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[I 11:01:29.346 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled.ipynb
/home/namehidden/miniconda3/envs/namehidden/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py:128: MissingIDFieldWarning: Code cell is missing an id field, this will become a hard error in future nbformat versions. You may want to use `normalize()` on your notebooks before validations (available since nbformat 5.1.4). Previous versions of nbformat are fixing this issue transparently, and will stop doing so in the future.
  validate(nb)
/home/namehidden/miniconda3/envs/namehidden/lib/python3.11/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py:353: MissingIDFieldWarning: Code cell is missing an id field, this will become a hard error in future nbformat versions. You may want to use `normalize()` on your notebooks before validations (available since nbformat 5.1.4). Previous versions of nbformat are fixing this issue transparently, and will stop doing so in the future.
  validate_nb(model['content'])
```

Specs:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Virtual Env: Conda
[image]